# Rename [tsql] to [t-sql]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Can we please rename the tag [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) to [t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/t-sql)? This falls in line with the documented name [Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) which is abbreviated to T-SQL in documentation (not TSQL).

There are over 70,000 questions, so this isn't a simple case of a member (or several members) of the community retagging them.

I also can't create the new tag [t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/t-sql) and suggest [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) as a synonym as the new tag is too similar to [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql):

> The tag [t-sql] is too similar to [tsql]. If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: This can be done by normal users by finding 3 other users, adding the [tag:t-sql] tag to some relevant questions (such that you each have a score of 5 in [tag:t-sql], and then synonymizing [tsql] to [t-sql] (might take a day to update scores though) and having those other three users vote for it. Not _super_ efficient, but it doesn't require mods or employees to do, and if you're coordinated it can be done in the span of ~24 hours.

Comment: I say this method mostly because, if the tag were renamed, we would definitely want [tag:tsql] to be re-created and then synonymized to [tag:t-sql] so we don't get two competing tag names.

Comment: I admit I haven't *tried* creating it, @TylerH , but I also suspect I'll be told it's "too similar to [tsql]".

Comment: Yep, that's [exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WWuP.png) what happened, @TylerH .

Comment: Oh, that's a good point, yes, it is blocked due to being too similar.

Comment: "An unknown error has occurred; please try again later." when trying to rename the tag so.... I'll put in a bug report to see if someone can figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/t-sql) now matches the abbreviation in the official documentation. I've kept [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) as a synonym (this way any bookmarks and links will redirect automatically).

As this was a rather significant tag merge, it will take some time for things to settle.

```
updating post history, 0 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 72742 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 't-sql' doesn't exist, renaming 'tsql' to 't-sql'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [t-sql] and [tsql] complete!
remapping 1 synonyms
19006 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
799 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Note to a future Moderator: It appears that a straightforward rename failed to create the [t-sql] tag because it is too similar to [tsql]. As a workaround, I was able to add a synonym from [t-sql] -> [tsql] to create the [t-sql] tag first, then swap the synonym direction [tsql] -> [t-sql]. The rename then worked as expected and functioned correctly as a tag rename.