# Incorrect gold badge notification in inbox

Tags: bug, badges, tag-badges

I apparently just earned the gold database tag today, as indicated by my profile here:

[image: screen capture of profile badges]

However, the notification I received in my inbox erroneosly mentions the gold t-sql badge:

[image: screen capture of inbox]

Notes:

- The gold t-sql badge was the next most recent gold badge I had earned, prior to the database badge.
- I have never observed this behavior for any other gold badge.
- I guess it is possible this has happened for a bronze/silver badge, as I do not track them so closely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You earned the [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) gold tag badge on September 12, not today, but this is purely a coincidence (if that). What's evidently happening here is that you earned the [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) tag badge at some point in the past, but that was [renamed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426551/6083675) to [t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/t-sql) (with a hyphen) and it was re-awarded. This is the first time I've ever seen a tag so popular get renamed, so it's not likely that this behavior is happening a lot.

Comment: You are correct. The tag was renamed so when tag-badge scores were recalculated all 41 users with the [tsql gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/200/tsql) "lost" their tag badge because they no longer met the requirements and were awarded the [t-sql gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11809/t-sql). This is also true of those users who held bronze and silver tsql tag badges.

Comment: As an aside, it'd be great if it would just rename the badges too. It's a bit sad that users can't see how long they've held these badges anymore since they were all awarded simultaneously "today". That was certainly not my intention in updating the tag name...